# Intervene in definition of every class in python implicitly using metaclasses?

Tags: python, global, metaclass

I've been learning about metaclasses, and I was wondering if it's possible to add a new attribute to every class that's defined in python, not just those which inherit explicitly from a custom metaclass.

I can add a new attribute explicitly using a custom metaclass like this

```py
class NewAttrMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs['new_attr'] = 'new_thing'
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class A(metaclass=NewAttrMeta):
   ...

print(A.new_attr)
$ 'new_thing'
```

But is it possible to force a change like this on **every** class that's defined, not just the ones which explicitly inherit from your custom metaclass?

I thought maybe as all classes are of type `type`, if I overwrote `type` itself with my custom metaclass, then all new classes might then inherit from it. And as metaclasses are subclasses of `type`, then all classes defined that way would still be valid...

```py
class NewAttrMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs['new_attr'] = 'new_thing'
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

type = NewMagicMeta
```

But this only works if `type` is passed in explicitly again:

```py
class A(type):
   ...

print(A.new_attr)
$ 'new_thing'

class B():
   ...

print(B.new_attr)
$ AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'new_attr'
```

Why on earth am I trying to do this? I wanted to see if I could locally implement a version of the rejected [PEP 472: "Support for indexing with keyword arguments"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0472/) by overriding the `__getitem__` method of every class which defined any version of `__getitem__`. I'm only doing this for fun, so I would be interested in any insights or alternative ways to do that (the hackier the better!).

Comment: To monkey patch built in classes and methods globally you need to do it on the `builtins` module (`__builtin__` for Python2) -> `import builtins; builtins.type = foo`

Comment: Interesting - but that doesn't seem to work. Adding `import builtins; builtins.type = NewAttrMeta` still gives the same `AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'new_attr'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Python does not allow modification of built-in declared types. That
   means that dictionaries, lists, classes defineds in extensions like
   Numpy.ndarrays are "frozen" from Python code.
2. Even if that where possible, changing the metaclass for all classes would not change classes already defined. So, `list`, etc... would not have affected. You could arrange your program so that it could "install" your class creation hooks before importing any other modules with class definition, though - so it could affect classes written in Python code.  (Classes created in extensions are defined in C code and do not go through the metaclass-class creation process anyway)
3. `type` is referenced as the metaclass for object, so even if you change `type` in the builtins - which is possible, that won't automatically be used as a metaclass for anyone. It is used by default because it is what is returned by `type(object)`

All that said, it is possible to create something that would seek through all *existing* classes in a running Python program, and, whenever the class is defined in Python, to decorate a `__getitem__` method if it exists, to accept keyword parameters.

But then:

1. The support with indexing arguments as proposed in PEP 472 requires changes to the parser and to the language specification - simply accepting keyword arguments in `__getitem__` won´t make `a[b=1]` work, or not be a syntax error. One would still have to write `a.__getitem__(b=1)`
2. An index name in `__getitem__` is something very specific for a kind of objects. There is no way it would make sense for *any* class designed without that in mind. If `a` is a list, what `a[fish='golden']` would mean? And what if `a` is a dict?

All in all, you'd already have a very cool class if you would come up with something for which it makes sense to have name passed in the index - and then you could just have any method to retrieve it, and use the regular parentheses notation for that `a.get(fish="gold")`, or even, if you write the  `__call__` method: `a(fish="gold")`

Comment: Thank you, very informative. Yeah I realised after posting that PEP472 would need changes to the parser. You would need `__getitem__` to keep the old behaviour in addition to the new, of course. The "very cool class" which inspired this was the hope for [indexing with dimension names in xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#indexing-with-dimension-names).